# How to add label and textfiled to each row in the UITableview

Tags: iphone

How to add label and textfiled to each row in the UITableview. can i add it through the Interface builder or have to do in the code,

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: I did it but you should vote good answers (there r many in ur previous questions) and accept before asking any question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either make a custom table view cell class yourself, or you can use one of the [built-in cell styles](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellStyle). Apple's "Settings" panel, for example, uses `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`.

Then you would set the detailTextLabel to the text, and add a sub view (your text field) to the contentView for your cell.

```
static NSString *CellID = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellID];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellID] autorelease];
}

cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"a title";
[cell.contentView addSubview: xyz]; // xyz = your text field
```